# MergeSort on ArrayList only work with ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) not ArrayList(int initialCapacity)?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, mergesort

I am working on sort `interval` which exist on an `ArrayList` with its `start` property, the full definition of `interval` will show in sample code as private class.

The implementation I am using is `MergeSort`, and very similar to [Princeton's stuff](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/22mergesort/Merge.java.html) which I refer to, but problem is I find this implementation **only work with** creating auxiliary `ArrayList aux` with `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` and initialize it with `aux.set(i, intervals.get(i));` which try to fill `aux` with same order of `interval` items from original list

I try to work it out with creating `aux` with `ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` and initialize it with `aux.add(intervals.get(i))`, but failed. And I still could not figure out why this way doesn't work ?

The full code which can directly used for debug:

```
public class Test {
    private class Interval {
        // Will use start property to sort
        int start;
        int end;
        Interval() { 
            start = 0; 
            end = 0; 
        }
        Interval(int s, int e) { 
            start = s; 
            end = e; 
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + start + "," + end + "]";
        }
    }

    public void sortHelper(List<Interval> intervals) {
        int len = intervals.size();
        // Only this way works
        List<Interval> aux = new ArrayList<Interval>(intervals);
        // This way NOT work ?
        //List<Interval> aux = new ArrayList<Interval>(len);
        sort(intervals, aux, 0, len - 1);
    }

    public void sort(List<Interval> intervals, List<Interval> aux, int lo, int hi) {
        if(hi <= lo) {
            return;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(intervals, aux, lo, mid);
        sort(intervals, aux, mid + 1, hi);
        mergeHelper(intervals, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    }

    public void mergeHelper(List<Interval> intervals, List<Interval> aux, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        // Only this way works
        for(int i = lo; i <= hi; i++) {
            aux.set(i, intervals.get(i));
        }
        // Combine with List<Interval> aux = new ArrayList<Interval>(len);
        // this way NOT work ?
        //for(int i = lo; i <= hi; i++) {
        //    aux.add(intervals.get(i));
        //}
        int left = lo;
        int right = mid + 1;
        for(int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            if(left > mid) {
                intervals.set(k, aux.get(right++));
            } else if(right > hi) {
                intervals.set(k, aux.get(left++));
            } else if(less(aux.get(right), aux.get(left))) {
                intervals.set(k, aux.get(right++));
            } else {
                intervals.set(k, aux.get(left++));
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean less(Interval a, Interval b) {
        return a.start - b.start < 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test m = new Test();
        Interval one = m.new Interval(1, 3);
        Interval two = m.new Interval(2, 6);
        Interval three = m.new Interval(8, 10);
        Interval four = m.new Interval(15, 18);
        List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        // Adding order as [2,6],[1,3],[8,10],[15,18]
        intervals.add(two);
        intervals.add(one);
        intervals.add(three);
        intervals.add(four);
        m.sortHelper(intervals);
        // Expected sort result should be
        // [1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]
        for(Interval i : intervals) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }    
}
```

Could anyone help me on understanding why must create auxiliary `ArrayList aux` with `ArrayList<Collection<? extends E> c>` and initialize it with `aux.set(i, intervals.get(i));` ? Or my understanding goes the wrong way ?
Thanks

Comment: @maraca, thanks, but could you double check again, actually i am not using ArrayList with primitive types, the ArrayList<int initialCapacity> is just a constructor I am using for initialize the ArrayList with limited length, the real items are `Interval` type as declared as private class

Comment: Yes I saw in the code and removed the comment. But your two lines are not doing the same, one is making a copy and one is creating an empty array with some capacity.

Comment: @maraca, that's right, I know the difference between these two constructors, but problem is why need such a copy of original list ? just initialize a new empty list then adding with same order items from original list will not work with MergeSort, Even more, if you just use `new ArrayList<Interval>(intervals)` to copy a list but **without** `aux.set(i, intervals.get(i));` also will not work, these things confused me, if you have time can run on IDE for behavior, thanks

Comment: Yes but don't forget that the sort method is called recursively and it calls the merge method, so you will be adding way too many elements.

Comment: The difference between `aux.set(i, ...)` and `aux.add(...)` is elements not being at the same indices, thus the rest of the code assuming they are at the same indices as the input won't work. Also, like maraca pointed out, your array will become unnecessarily large - if you want to do it that way, you should probably `aux.clear()` in `mergeHelper`.

Comment: @Dukeling,@maraca, thanks for sharing ideas

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for important hint from @maraca and @Dukeling, after some work, below is my opinion for the issue here:

**Q1**: Why using `List<Interval> aux = new ArrayList<Interval>(len);` with `aux.add(intervals.get(i));` not work ?

**A1**: There are two main issues here, I should admit I fail into some habitual thoughts as previous work with `array` implementation of `MergeSort`, the impact here are (1) `new ArrayList<Interval>(len)` equal to `new Interval[len]` or not ? (2) `aux[i] = intervals[i]`(just for explain, not use `=` in real code) equal to `aux.add(intervals.get(i))` ?

For problem (1), the real case here is using `new ArrayList<Interval>(len)` will only define the initial limitation of `ArrayList` size, but no real items used like space holder to fill into the initialized list, e.g If we set `len = 4`, the initialized list is actually `[]`, not `[interval obj, interval obj, interval obj, interval obj]`. Assume using `new ArrayList<Interval>(len)` with `aux.set(i, intervals.get(i))`, IDE will throw out `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`, that's because no real object fill into this list as initialized and set method cannot work on an empty list. The solution for this issue is create `len` numbers of dummy `interval` objects to fill in list when initialized, such as
`List<Interval> aux = new ArrayList<Interval>((Arrays.asList(new Interval(), new Interval(), new Interval(), new Interval())));`, but since we don't care what initialized first on auxiliary list, just used as place holder and in case of the objects are too many, above code can be replaced with `List<Interval> aux = new ArrayList<Interval>(intervals);` which return to our right solution.

For problem (2), the real case here is using `aux.add(intervals.get(i))` not equal to `aux[i] = intervals[i]`, at least we should use `set()` instead of `add()`, because `add()` will continually append on `aux`, which not `MergeSort` suppose to, because `MergeSort` require exactly same size auxiliary collection copy to help sorting. Still use same example to explain what happened when using `add()`

[image]

Note after the 3rd merge, the `aux` size increase to double size of original list, this will cause indices issue when copy back to original list. But if we are using `set()` will not cause this trouble.

**Q2**: If still want to use `add()` what is the proper way ?

**A2**: As mentioned by @Dukeling, we need to `clear()` the `aux` before final round copy from original list to auxiliary list, e.g like before the 3rd merge happen on above example.

The working code with `add()` and `clear()` below:

```
public void mergeHelper(List<Interval> intervals, List<Interval> aux, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    aux.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < lo; i++) {
        aux.add(null);
    }
    for(int i = lo; i <= hi; i++) {
        aux.add(intervals.get(i));
    }
    int left = lo;
    int right = mid + 1;
    for(int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
        if(left > mid) {
            intervals.set(k, aux.get(right++));
        } else if(right > hi) {
            intervals.set(k, aux.get(left++));
        } else if(less(aux.get(right), aux.get(left))) {
            intervals.set(k, aux.get(right++));
        } else {
            intervals.set(k, aux.get(left++));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty close, except for A1 (2): a[i] = b[i] is the same as a.set(i, b.get(i)). Add always adds an additional element a.add(i, b.get(i)) would insert the element at position i and shift those after it (if the index is ommitted the element is added after the last position).

Comment: If you are populating an array with counter like arr[counter++] = something, then this corresponds more or less to a list.add(something).